# Passing at-sign character to procmail in virtusertable

Tags: sendmail, procmail, email

The FAQ tip at http://www.sendmail.org/faq/section3#3.29 seems to rely on the fact that the following entry in virtusertable:

```
@domain.com   user+%1
```

will cause $1 in the .procmailrc config, e.g.:

```
ENV_TO=$1
```

to have the value "xyz" if email received was for xyz@domain.com and "abc" for abc@domain.com. (Viewing the procmail log seems to confirm this.)

However, I'd like to have $1 have the value "xyz@domain.com" instead.  This is so I can do processing for multiple domain names under the same user.

The following virtusertable/.procmailrc config seems to work for this purpose:

virtusertable:

```
@domain1.com   userA+%1\@domain1.com
@domain2.com   userA+%1\@domain2.com
```

.procmailrc:

```
ENV_TO=$1

:0f
* ENV_TO ?? .
| formail -i "X-Envelope-To: $ENV_TO"

:0fE
| formail -i "X-Envelope-To: UNKNOWN"

:0:
* ^X-Envelope-To: xyz\\@domain1.com
$HOME/userA/domain1.com/mail/xyz

:0:
* ^X-Envelope-To: abc\\@domain2.com
$HOME/userA/domain2.com/mail/abc
```

However, I'd like to avoid having to the double backslashes appear in X-Envelope-To.  Removing [what seems to be] the quoting backslash in the virtusertable fails, e.g.:

```
@domain1.com   userA+%1@domain1.com
@domain2.com   userA+%1@domain2.com
```

seems to cause an "excessive recursion error".

My question is:

*How does one properly quote the at-sign in virtusertable, so that $1 that arrives in .procmailrc will only contain "abc@domain1.com" rather than "abc\@domain1.com"?*

Or, if that is not possible, how can we remove the backslash within .procmailrc processing itself so that ENV_TO is (ultimately) assigned "abc@domain1.com" rather than "abc\@domain1.com"?

Comment: The ambersand is [&](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambersand). I think you mean the % (percent) sign.

Comment: You're right, thanks for spotting the error, I meant the at-sign not ampersand.

Answer (score 1):

You make your virtusertable read like: `@domain.com user+%1-domain.com` and then you make a script that reads the `X-Envelope-To:`  header prepared from `formail` which replaces it with the proper value.  In other words, you need your own version of `formail` just for this purpose.  You can do that even with your current setup where you will have the script parse the `X-Envelope-To:` header and remove the backslash.

Comment: I stuck with \@ because the dash might appear in %1.  So my procmailrc now has X=$1; ENV_TO=`echo ${X} | sed 's/\\\@/@/'` to remove the backslash.  Was hoping for a less elaborate solution, e.g. no need for sed, but doesn't seem like there's one?